# How best practice with if statement loop?

Tags: design-patterns

I have code:

```
if(conditional)
{
   var r1 = dosomething();
   //do more here

   if(r1 > something)
   {
      var r2 = dosomething();
      //do something
      if(r2 > something)
      {
         ....
         //n if
      }
   }
}
```

I need help for this code is better. Can you show for me some suggestion?
Thanks all!

Comment: the problem is not clear to me. Can you be specific about the problem?

Comment: there is no best practice, except to make it work and make it readable.

Comment: did you meant to ask, how to optimize this code? (from what can i tell, this is the simplest you can get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = 0;
while (rN > somethingArray[i]){ //if your 'something' is changing in every if use array otherwise simple variable like (rN > something) will work
   rN = dosomething();
   i++;
}
```